# MongoDB: Using map-reduce to change string into integer

Tags: string, mongodb, mapreduce, integer

I am new here and asking a question for a mongodb related problem I have been facing.

Here is an example structure of how one record would look like.

```
{
    "_id" : {
             "id" : "lk23j",
             "language" : "English"
            },
   "class" : "test",
   "title" : {
              "duration" : "34"
              "year" : "1991"
             }
}
```

There are several records like this and I would like to take the sum of duration, in all records. To my understanding  aggregation would not work as `title.duration` field needs to be converted to integer, so taking the sum returns NaN(not a number). Hence I'll need to convert then take the sum using map-reduce which will allow parseInt(in javascript).

From http://blog.physalix.com/datas-manipulation-in-mongodb-rename-field-change-type-add-sub-document/, I was **unable** to change the title.duration to integer:

```
db.members.find().forEach( function (x) {x.title.duration= parseInt(x.title.duration);});
```

The query above threw a

> "cannot read property 'duration' of undefined".

I frequently get the error

> Invalid left-hand side in assinment" for "title.duration"= parseInt("title.duration");

I've tried a similar approach using map-reduce but had no success. I am having troubles referencing the data `title.duration`.

If someone can help out I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You could try filtering your collection for documents where the `title.duration` field is of string type and exists, then iterate over the **`find()`** cursor with the **`forEach`** method, do the conversion and save the updated document.

Let's take the minimum test case and insert the following test documents to a test collection:

```
db.test.insert([
    {
        "_id" : {
            "id" : "lk23j",
            "language" : "English"
        },
        "class" : "test",
        "title" : {
            "duration" : "34",
            "year" : "1991"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "id" : "abc",
            "language" : "French"
        },
        "class" : "foo"
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "id" : "def",
            "language" : "German"
        },
        "class" : "bar",
        "title" : {
            "year" : "1991"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "id" : "erb42",
            "language" : "Shona"
        },
        "class" : "xyz",
        "title" : {
            "duration" : null,
            "year" : "1993"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "id" : "urn321",
            "language" : "Latin"
        },
        "class" : "bar",
        "title" : {
            "duration" : "",
            "year" : "1999"
        }
    }
])
```

The conversion operation as described above can then be carried out as follows:

```
db.test.find({ "title.duration": { "$type" : 2 } }).forEach(function (doc){ 
    doc.title.duration = parseInt(doc.title.duration) || 0;
    db.test.save(doc);
});
```

After the conversion you can then use the aggregation framework to calculate the sum on the `title.duration` field for all documents as follows:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total_duration": {
                "$sum": "$title.duration"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

And the result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "total_duration" : 34
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Must I save first? I wasn't able to see the changes when doing a db.test.find(). If not, is there another way to do this without saving. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLiang Yes, you need to save first else you will always get the values as strings.

Comment: Is there a way to execute this query without saving? For instance,  could we use map-reduce?